# Controlling bluetooth playback using car steering wheel control

Tags: raspberry-pi, pulseaudio, bluetooth, bluez

I'm trying to use a RPI 4 as an audio source for my car (note that most information on the net does the opposite i.e. they talk about using RPI as a bluetooth speaker). I'm also posting the question here, because I don't believe this is RPI specific problem.

So far I successfully configured A2DP protocol, and I can play music in my car or any bluetooth headset without a problem. I'm running into a problem though, I want to use my steering wheel controls to control the playback (play/pause/next song/previous song), and don't see any of them, they don't register on dbus and /dev/input/event0 while it exists nothing shows up with evtest.

I did some research and tried to make it work with a portable bluetooth speaker, this time the input device worked and I was able to control it, so I know RPI is capable of doing it.

Today I had another breakthrough, when connecting RPI as a media device I noticed that my car doesn't display fields with artist/album/title (with my phone it always displays them even when nothing plays), so I tried to connect other phones as players and learned that OnePlus 6 shows these fields as well  and can be controlled by the steering wheel, while LG G6 phone behaves similarly to RPI and the steering wheel controls also don't work.

My conclusion is that when devices authenticate to the car they advertise a feature that makes the car enable/disable steering wheel control and media information. Makes me wonder what the feature is and how to make bluez5 advertise it? I'm guessing it is not AVRCP, since RPI worked with portable bluetooth speaker? Unless it is the version that's being advertised?

I also will probably need some guidance how to send artist/album/song to the car.

If it helps the car I'm trying this on is Prius 2015 Four.